# Apply CSS fill on an star element

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm using star element from - http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/star-o/

and I want to fill it with color, the `color: red;` only applies to the surrounding of the element, couldn't find out the right definition for the all star.
My code:

```
<i class="fa fa-star-o" ng-click="alertStar(1)" id="1"></i>
```

And the CSS :

```
#1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using? I have a vague idea, but it'll be much better if you show us the code! :)

Comment: BTW `#1` may not work, you will have to use #\31 in order to escape the numbered ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to FontAwesome's documentation, it has a lot of classes for each of the icons provided. The `star` icon has a couple of classes which may interest you:

```
<i class="fa fa-star">
<i class="fa fa-star-o">
```

The second one is just an outline for it. To get the desired effect, you can give it the `.fa-star` class and then use CSS to color it.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hdkzfue1/

---

You can use the `icon-star` class which will give you a filled star; you can, later, color it using the `color` rule.

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle please?

Comment: Have a look! I have added the example.

Comment: Do you know the proprty for the star outter line(shape)?

Comment: Yeah! It's `.fa-star-o`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a color for your general font awesome classes u can use this code:

```
.fa {color: red;}
```

If you want to go class specific u can use this code:

```
.fa .fa-star-o {color: red;}
```

Comment: I wrote that it only applies to the star surroundings and not the fill.

Comment: @ArneBanck, the OP has already told you what he/she has tried.

Comment: How about u take a breather and stop downvoting people . The .fa-star-o code was right it changed the outline color and did not fill. Atleast try the code before u take a jab at fellow coders thank you :)

Comment: I am sorry but have a look at my answer. It's the way we keep this community clean; the OP said that he/she has tried it (it's clearly visible from the code).

Comment: U literally gave the same answer as me, dont try to disrespect me.

Comment: I most certainly did not. Let's not continue this here as it's just futile and also 'contaminates' the forum.

Comment: K bud take the credit, enjoy your coding life. There will always be people like you.